# Is it possible to Update MongoDb documents using forEach method?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Good day Stack Overflow community :),

I can't figure out or if it is actually possible to Update documents using forEach in MongoDB or anything similar to solve my problem. I'll try to explain the problem and what I've tried to the best of my ability.

1. Here is a mock database I created using MongoDB and it looks like this, the _id isn't relevant to the question only the orderId, which I will write about below:

```json
    {
      "_id": "5fb812f7cd2b101374aa2bd8",
      "orderId": 322,
      "provider": "Barion Bistro"
    },{
      "_id": "5fb812f7cd2b101374aa2bd9",
      "orderId": 400,
      "provider": "Glacier Hotel"
    },{
      "_id": "5fb812f7cd2b101374aa2asd",
      "orderId": 1212,
      "provider": "HM Store"
    },{
      "_id": "5fb812f7cd2b101374aa2bbd",
      "orderId": 322,
      "provider": "Funky Town"
    },{
      "_id": "5fb812f7cd2b101374aa2bb2",
      "orderId": 3223,
      "provider": "Cocktails Bar"
    }
```

2. What I'm trying to accomplish is to use the MongoDB update function in order to update the orderId. I can easily change them to all at once (total 5), but I want to do something different forEach of the documents, hence all at once. By using the following query below, the same orderId will be set for the whole database, i.e. all the providers Barion Bistro, Glacier Hotel, etc... will all have the same orderId, which will be 2 after running the query below.

```js
    db.coupons.update({},   
      $set: {
        orderId: 2
      }
    }, {
      multi: true
    })
```

3. What i'm trying to accomplish is to set the orderId for each provider, i.e. the first provider Barion Bistro will have orderId: 1, the second provider will have orderId: 2, the third provider HM Store will have orderId: 3, etc.

I've been stuck on this problem for a week and can't figure out if it's solvable using MongoDB update. What I've tried is using the following query which doesn't work, and I want to know if anyone has solved a similar problem as I'm having. The query is the following:

```js
    var counter = 1;
    
    db.coupons.update({
     $set: { doc.counterId: counter },
     { multi: true }
    }
    ).forEach(doc => { 
      counter = counter + 1
    })
```

Hope anyone can lead me into the right direction.
Best regards,
Peter

**UPDATE 11/21/2020**

Okay RLD is a legend, he solved it!

Comment: If you have a solution please post it as reply and mark as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using latest **MongoDB** i.e., version **>= 4.2**, then you can use **forEach** method following way:

```
var counter=1;
db.coupons.find().forEach( function (d) {
     db.coupons.updateOne({"_id":d._id},[{"$set":{"orderId": counter}}]);
     counter++;
})
```

Comment: This is the third time I edit this comment haha, after going back and fourth your solution works 100%. Thank you for your time and help, much appreciated!